# Send request for Turned Based Battle

Tags: php, turn-based, ajax

I want to create a turn based battle system for Pokemon online rpg!

I will some how implement the coding of the battle..but I want to know how can a user send request for a battle to other user?

If a user wants to have a live battle with some other user, he will send a battle request!
If the opponent wants to battle he will accept it otherwise it will be rejected and no battle will take place...!

How can I implement the above??

Comment: Yes, tell us what you've tried already and what about it didn't work. This gives us a starting point so that we can avoid telling you something you already know. It also drastically narrows the scope of the question, because there are dozens of ways to implement something like this. Finally, it will help solidify exactly what you want.

Comment: I have implemented, Login, Registration, Searching Pokemons on Maps, Who's Online, Team (6 pokemons), Change Team(replace pokemon from the team)
Everything is done yet only using PHP!

Comment: What you've completed so far is not the same thing as what you've tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some client Javascript and run AJAX regularly so you can run server-side PHP and check if there are any battle requests, or during combat turns to check for any player actions.